# What do we call one step in a resolution?

Tags: word-choice

Lets say, I have taken a resolution. And there are 5 steps in the process of accomplishing the resolution. Is there a word for each of those steps? A word other than "baby-step", "target", "milestone"?

- Milestone sounds bigger than resolution itself.
- Baby-step doesn't have the same seriousness as resolution.
- Target sounds more like and end-point. But, we are looking at something that's somwhere in the path to the target.

Comment: Why call it a _baby step_ when you can call it a _step_?

Comment: (As, indeed, you did in the question)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this in a business context, go with milestone. Else, I would suggest either "phase" or "stage."

Answer (score 2):

I would just use *step*. As in *first step*, *second step* etc.

You could also go with *objective*, as in

> I have achieved the third objective of my resolution.

In my opinion step is the best.

Answer (score 1):

***"Tasks"*** or ***"Sub-tasks"*** can be used for the steps (though "step" is still a very servicable option).  If you approach the resolution like a project, there is very useful information in this Wikipedia article on a project's [work breakdown structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management#Work_breakdown_structure).

Answer (score 0):

Useful synonyms are *event* and *waypoint* - the latter would have my preference

Answer (score 0):

In business or software development context you can use it as a milestone or checkpoint but in context of resolutions or goals you can use "Step" or "Baby Step".

Baby step comes with a connotation that no matter how big or small you need to take the step (ACTION). Remember "A journey of 1000 miles begins with a step"

You take (baby) steps to reach a milestone.

Baby steps or Tiny Habits help you reach your goals or resolutions.